# Looping & copying cells

Tags: vba, excel

Generally my macro goes through every "O" cell, checks if the row meets given requirements (not mentioned in this part of code) and copies surrounding cells on the side. I have two columns used in this part: "contract no"(M), "date"(O). The problem is that I try to use below method to go up to last the contract number and copy it as well. 
I do not get any error but the contract cell value does not paste. Could you tell me what I've done wrong?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWHFn.png]

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) = "" Then
    'Go up find contract number copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select                                                                     
    Loop                                                     
    ActiveSheet.Range("M" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy _
        Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("V" & ActiveCell.Row)
    'Go down and return to the last active cell
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 
    Loop
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
End If
```

Comment: What cell is selected at the begining?

Comment: At the beginning "O" (Date)

Comment: `.Range("V" & ActiveCell.Row)` is wrong syntax. Try `ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "V")`

Comment: @Variatus - what's wrong with `Range("V" & ActiveCell.Row)`?

Comment: You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: @Variatus Thank you I'll keep it in mind. However it didn't help me in this case.

Comment: My mistake - end of day benightedness! I will try to make up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue lays in your keeping relying on `ActiveCell` after

```
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
```

statement, that changes it ...

you're actually playing with fire when using `ActiveCell` together with `Select`/`Selection` coding pattern!

since I cannot see what's behind the code you showed, I must keep using `ActiveCell` reference and amend your code as per comments:

```
Dim cellToCopy As Range
With ActiveCell 'reference currently "active" cell
    If .Offset(0, -2) = "" Then 'if the cell two columns left of referenced (i.e. "active") cell is empty...
        Set cellToCopy = .Offset(0, -2).End(xlUp) '... set cell to copy as the first not empty one above the cell two columns left of referenced (i.e. "active") cell
    Else '... otherwise
        Set cellToCopy = .Offset(0, -2) 'set cell to copy as the one two columns left of referenced (i.e. "active") cell
    End If
    cellToCopy.Copy Destination:=Range("V" & .Row) 'copy the cell set as the one to be copied and paste it column V cell same row as reference (i.e. "active") cell
End With
```

Comment: @Trawa, any feedback?

Comment: I'm sorry for such a late reply. Thank you it worked! I'll keep in mind not to use select and activecell reference together.

Comment: you are welcome. as for the `Selection/Active` issue you may want to read [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1):

#### You didn't select the desired cell

Problem lies in this loop:

```
'Selecting cell from a column to the left
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
'Condition: cell value is not empty string
Do Until ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    'Selecting cell from previous row in the same column
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Loop
```

You're leaving the loop before you can `.Select` a cell.

Use this loop instead:

```
'Selecting cell from a column to the left
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
'Condition: cell value is not empty string
Do
    'Selecting cell from previous row in the same column
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Loop Until ActiveCell.Value <> ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use `ActiveCell` Your code can do quite unpredictable things to your worksheet if the wrong cell was selected, and so can my "improvement" thereof below.

```
Sub FindAndCopy()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim R As Long, C As Long

    With ActiveCell
        Set Ws = .Worksheet
        R = .Row
        C = .Column
    End With

    With Ws
        If Len(Trim(.Cells(R, C - 2).Value)) = 0 Then
            'Go up find contract number copy
            Do Until Len(.Cells(R, C - 2).Value)
                R = R - 1
            Loop
            .Cells(R, "M").Copy Destination:=.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "V")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I think the `ActiveCell` component in this code is still a source of great danger. However, as you see, at least the code doesn't change it which dispenses with the necessity of going back to it in the end.